# Visual Studio no me abre mi carpeta de trabajo

Tags: visual-studio

Buenas alguien sabe porque Visual Studio cuando quiero abrir mi archivo de trabajo llamado por ejemplo "PAGINA" me muestra los archivos y me da este mensaje de error

**El repositorio Git 'c:/Users/jordannjord/Desktop' contiene muchos cambios activos, solamente un subconjunto de las características de Git serán habilitadas.**

Comment: Tu repositorio lo tienes apuntando a Desktop?

Comment: No no estoy utilizando git

Comment: estaba haciendo un tutorial de gulp el abrio bien el archivo pero luego, le di en la pestaña click detecho sobre mi carpeta y le di quitar de la barra lateral , lo quise volver a abrir y ya no me muestra los archivos nada

Comment: holaa pudiste resolverlo? tengo el mismo problema hice lo mismo lo elimine el archivo desde la barra y ahora no me abre ninguna carpeta solo el archivo, desistalel el programa y instale uno nuevo ysigue igual